# Display entire content of a List within an Array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, vue.js, vue-component

I wish to display entire content of a list within array I am using within the export of the module - list all `participants` of an `event`.
I have another component that handles rendering of **all events**, so in this one I would just need to show data for **one** event.

My data:

```
events [
    {
        "id":1,
        "participants": ["John Smith",  "Victoria Abraham", "Anthony Manning"]
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "participants": ["Victoria Abraham",  "Lily Knox"]
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "participants": ["Lily Knox",  "Anthony Manning", "Joan Scott"]
    }   
]
```

Part of code that handles rendering of `events`.

```
<template v-for="event in events">
       Participants:
        <li v-for="participant in event.participants" :key="participant">{{ event.participants[participant] }}</li>
</template>
```

Currently this results in displaying empty bullet list for each event, but with correct number of bullets.
Output of code above:

```
Event 1
Participants:
-
-
-

Event 2
Participants:
-
-

Event 3
Participants:
-
-
-
```

Answer (score 2):

The `participant` in your `li` refers to the name of the participant and not the index of the participants list.

write `participant` instead of `event.participants[participant]` in your li body